# Updating Chrome storage object key value

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension and I'm saving information using the `chrome.storage.sync.set` function. According to the API you can create an object and save the information between accounts. While I am not having any trouble creating this object, I am having trouble updating a specific key and syncing the value, without making an entirely separate object for each change.

For example my object looks something like this when logged to the console:

```
{
    profile: {
        preferences: {
            username: 'my username'
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to simply update the value 'username'.

I've tried doing something like this (I have access to the object through the chrome.storage.sync.set function callback):

```
_ext.profile.preferences.username = 'my new username';
```

This does update the object, but does not save and store it.

I have also tried this method:

```
_ext.profile.preferences.username = 'my new username 2'; /* update the key value */
chrome.storage.sync.set(_ext.profile) /* save the entire object to memory */
```

This method has not worked either.

What do you think is the problem here? Is it the way in which I'm trying to save the object or is there a better method to having a settings based approach?

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling "get" right away, before the "set" has completed, that could be the problem. Your example does not show a callback being passed to handle completion of the "set".

Comment: I can call and retrieve data just fine. For example, you can use the `set` methods callback to access the stored data. However, when I try using the example I gave in my description and then refresh my page no data is shown as updated.

Comment: Just revising this comment I left; after some experimentation I found out that I need to store the entire object to make an update. You can't update single key portions at this point without re-storing your object.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across your post while looking to solve the same issue. I ended up using a similar approach as React Redux state management. Instead of trying to manipulate the stored data, I make a copy then replace it.

```
var data = {}; 
chrome.storage.sync.get(function(result){
data = result.storedData;
data.profile.preferences.username = 'my new username';
});  
chrome.storage.sync.set({'storedData': data});
```